# Show that the number of groups of order 8181 is equal to the number of groups of order 81 (up to isomorphism)

Tags: group-theory

> Show that the number of nonisomorphic groups of order $8181=3^4\cdot 101$ is equal to the number of nonisomorphic groups of order $81$. Find all the abelian groups of order $8181$ and at least one that is not abelian.

the second part (finding all abelian groups) doesn't seem very hard. But I don't know how to approach the first part. I tried applying the Sylow theorems but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part we proof that each such group $G$ is isomorphic to a direct product of the cyclic group $\mathbb Z_{101}$ of order $101$ and a group $H$ of order $81$, i.e.,
$$ G \cong H \times \mathbb Z_{101} $$

By Sylow's first theorem there exists a $101$-Sylow subgroup $G_{101}$ of order $101$. Let $n_{101}$ denote the number of $101$-Sylow subgroups then by Sylow's third theorem $n_{101} | 81$ and $n_{101} \equiv 1 \; (\mathrm{mod}\; 101)$. It follows that $n_{101} \leq 81$ and therefore $n_{101} = 1$. Since all conjugates of a $p$-Sylow are $p$-Sylow themselves, $\mathbb Z_{101} \cong G_{101}$ is normal in $G$.

Now let $G_{81}$ be a $3$-Sylow subgroup of order $81$ in $G$. Again this exists by Sylow's first theorem. As before we denote by $n_{3}$ the number of its conjugates of $G_{81}$ and therefore the number of $3$-Sylow subgroups in $G$. We have $n_{81} | 101$ and $n_{81} \equiv 1 \; (\mathrm{mod}\; 81)$. Again this leaves no other choice but $n_{81} = 1$ and $G_{81}$ is normal in $G$.

Finally, let $a \in G_{81} \cap G_{101}$ then the order of $a$ must divide $81$ and $101$ and since these are relative prime, the intersection is trivial. We conclude, that
$$ G = G_{81} \times G_{101} \cong H \times \mathbb Z_{101},$$
where $H$ denotes a group of order $81$. This implies that there at least as many groups of order $81$ as there are groups of order $8181$. On the other hand, using this direct product we can easily construct a group of order $8181$ from a given group $H$ of order $81$. So the numbers must coincide.

Finding the abelian groups of order $8181$ is a direct application the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups.

As for the example of a non-abelian group pick any non-abelian group of orded 81, e.g., any of [these.](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_81) And define $G$ as its direct product with $\mathbb Z_{101}$.

Answer (score 1):

Both the Sylow $3$-subgroup and the Sylow $101$-subgroup are normal, so a group $G$ of order $8181$ is a direct product $A\times B$ where $A$ is of order $81$ and $B$ is of order $101$. There is a unique isomorphism class of groups of order $101$, so a group of order $8181$ is just the direct product of a group of order $81$ with a cyclic group of order $101$. The claim follows.

To find a nonabelian group, it's enough to find a nonabelian group of order $27$. There is one of those, it's a standard example of a finite group with exponent $3$ that is not abelian.